# How to select injected HTML's li and keep it hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how can i keep li with  `iconsrc="/_layouts/15/images/delitem.gif"`  image hidden as this div is injected by first party and I am third party trying to hide it.

```
$("<style> what will go here ???? { display: none; }</style>").appendTo(document.documentElement);
```

How can I select list item with `iconsrc="/_layouts/15/images/delitem.gif"` from document.

```
<div class="ms-core-menu-box ms-core-menu-hasIcons ms-core-defaultFont ms-shadow" title="" dir="ltr" contenteditable="false" style="top: 0px; position: absolute; visibility: visible; left: -129px; width: 127px;" flipped="false">
    <ul class="ms-core-menu-list">
        <li type="option" text="Delete" onmenuclick="spgridcontainer_WPQ2_rowcontextmenu_onclick(0);" iconsrc="/_layouts/15/images/delitem.gif" iconalttext="Delete" enabled="true" checked="undefined" id="mp43_0_0" class="ms-core-menu-item">
            <a class="ms-core-menu-link" id="mp43_0_0_Anchor" href="javascript:;" onclick="return false;" title="Delete">
                <div class="ms-core-menu-icon">
                    <img src="/_layouts/15/images/delitem.gif" alt="Delete" title="Delete" id="mp43_0_0_ICON">
                </div>
                <div class="ms-core-menu-label" id="">
                    <span class="ms-core-menu-title">Delete</span>
                    <span></span>
                </div>
                <span class="ms-accessible"></span>
                <div></div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Point is keep delete button hidden whenever this list is injected in into the page.

Comment: And what about `$('#mp43_0_0').hide();`?

Comment: @Regent IDs are more likely to change in future then image, so I want to stick to that --- and also this object not ALWAYS is present in DOM so I need to add it to CSS unless there's any better way

Comment: Selecting `li` based on `iconsrc` value: `$('li[iconsrc="/_layouts/15/images/delitem.gif"]').hide();`

Comment: If object is not in DOM, this code will do nothing - what is the problem?

Comment: I need to hide a list menu option of a first party product, and they are injecting it using code, so only option i can think of is adding a css for that item and maybe adding "!important" to it if required

Comment: maybe I can add an event to body, whenever a new div is added - hide using code you listed above, but i am google to do that as i have limited knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple with css attribute selectors:

```css
li[iconsrc="/_layouts/15/images/delitem.gif"] {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li iconsrc="/_layouts/15/images/delitem.gif">
        <img src="/_layouts/15/images/delitem.gif" alt="Delete" title="Delete" id="mp43_0_0_ICON" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="/_layouts/15/images/adasdasfafsdfs.gif" alt="sdfsdfsdf" title="Blablalbavbaab" id="fsdfsdfsdf"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Would love to, but product is multi-language so title won't going to remain same and it is translated to 10's of languages

Comment: @THE is there anything constant in the delete button? or everything about it is variable? you could as well select it with `img[src='/_layouts/15/images/delitem.gif']`

Comment: iconsrc="/_layouts/15/images/delitem.gif"  is the most constant attr here

Answer (score 0):

you can use list's id attribute in the style tag to keep it hidden:

```
<style>
  li#mp43_0_0 {
      display: none;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: PLease check my question, i said i want to use image to select li item not id, id keeps changing, thanks

Answer (score 0):

may be try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('ul li').each(function(idx, li) {
 if($(li).attr('iconsrc') =='/_layouts/15/images/delitem.gif'){
   $(li).hide();
 }
});
});
```

Comment: It is the longer version of what I have suggested, but OP doesn't like it, because `<li>` is added somehow dynamically.